# Angular [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular

Buenas estoy aprendiendo angular desde cero y quisiera saber como puedo acceder a los datos en el dom y en la consola, estoy usando angular 11, les remito el codigo (no tengo problemas en acceder a la api, solo no se como acceder a los datos ya traidos):

pokemon.service.ts
'''

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PokemonService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPokemon(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100000&offset=0');
  }
}
```

'''
app.component.ts
'''

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PokemonService } from './pokemon.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AppAngular';
  pokemones:any = '';
  constructor(private pokemon:PokemonService){

  }
  searchPokemon(){
    this.pokemones = this.pokemon.getPokemon().subscribe(data=> JSON.stringify(data.results[0]['name']));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.pokemones))
  }
}
```

'''
'''

```
<div class="content" role="main">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Pokemon"> <button (click)="searchPokemon()">Search Pokemon Api</button>
    <ul *ngIf="pokemones == ''">No hay Nada</ul>
    <ul *ngIf="pokemones != ''">{{ pokemones }}</ul>
</div>
```

'''

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código de la pregunta debe ir en formato texto y no en imagen. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia lo que haga falta. De lo contrario tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás recibiendo es una respuesta JSON, y para acceder a los datos tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
<div class="content" role="main">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search Pokemon"> <button (click)="searchPokemon()">Search Pokemon Api</button>
    <ul *ngIf="pokemones == ''">No hay Nada</ul>
    <ul *ngIf="pokemones != ''">{{ pokemones | json }}</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias ya pude resolver la opcion es guardar el data del subscribe en la variable que estaba guardando por defecto dentro de dicho subscribe ejemplo: this.pokemon.getPokemon().subscribe(data=> this.pokemones = data.results); y en el html acceder los key o values gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ok estimado, saludos.